# 'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'apply'

Tags: python, extract, apply, numeric

1. Trying to extract numeric part from column-dtype('O') and have the extracted data in a new column or replace the existing column.
2. In this process the apply method didnt work for the code below. Provided the traceback also

***code***

```
def dpr_size(data_size):
    split_size = re.split('(\d*.*\d)', data_size)
    size = float(split_size[0])
    return float(size)

df1['size_new'] = df1.size.astype('str').apply(dpr_size)
```

### ***Traceback***

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      5     return float(size)
      6 
----> 7 df1['size_new'] = df1.size.apply(dpr_size)

AttributeError: 'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'apply'

3. Tried many other alternatives, and now the below code works.
   ***code***
   `df1['size'] = df1['size'].astype('str')
   for i in range(len(df1['size'])):
   split_size = re.split('(\d*.*\d)', df1['size'][i])[1:]
   df1['size'][i] = split_size[0]`
4. However want to find out why 'apply' doesnt work

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBL5v.png)

Comment: Can you please explain “isn’t working”, giving a traceback?

Comment: This isnt working. Getting AttributeError: 'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'apply'.

Comment: @ Arya McCarthy Below code gives TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object ***code*** df1['size_new'] = re.split('(\d*.*\d)', df1['size'].astype('str'))

Comment: Your code doesn’t match what’s in the question. Please edit the question to include the code that was actually executed and the full trace back (not just the last line).

Comment: @Arya McCarthy - updated the question part. please check